# what is the diff between REMOTE_ADDR and LOCAL_ADDR

Tags: elmah

I found issue in elmah log about some exceptions (apparently related attract to my web site)

what is the diff between REMOTE_ADDR and LOCAL_ADDR in Elmah log ?

what does it means if IPs are different ? is it some VPN ?

Comment: Quite old documentation but still covers this [IIS Server Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx)